# How to set home screen in portrait and other screens in landscape in android Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to set home screen(first screen of app) in portrait mode and other screens in landscape mode using libgdx in android.
If I change manifest file then either it will apply that mode to all screen or it will change according to rotation of screen. I do not want that. i want Home screen in portrait(fixed) and others in landscape mode(fixed). 
Please help me.

Comment: from manifest file also you can specify orientation for each and every activity specifically.

Comment: You can use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hadler. 
and make your androidclass implements that handler and change orientation accordingly

make an interface name it CustomHandler(edit: custom handler class goes in your core module)
like this:

```
public interface CustomHandler {
public void setOrientationPortrait();
public void setOrientationLandscape();
}
```

now make your android class implements CustomHandler like this

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements CustomHandler {

    @Override
    public void setOrientationPortrait(){
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOrientationLandscape(){
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        androidPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        View gameView = initializeForView(new GameClass(this), config);
        setContentView(gameView);    
}
```

and in your GameClass that is in core module

simply call whenever you want to change orientation

```
public static CustomHandler handler;

public GameClass(CustomHandler handler){
    this.handler = handler;
}
```

then on any screen or stage

call it like this

```
GameClass.handler.setOrientationPortait();
//or
GameClass.handler.setOrientationLandscape();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> For portrait screen orientation

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

> For landscape screen orientation

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```